# Access $scope from within $scope.$on

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-broadcast

I have this code:

```
.directive('hostelGridBed', function($rootScope){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      config: '=',
      range: '=',
      days: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element){

    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.innerStay = '';
      function switchStay(data){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('SwitchStay', {data: data.config});
      };
      $scope.onDropComplete = function(data,evt){
        //$rootScope.$broadcast
        switchStay(data);
        console.log('Drop completo bed!');
      }
    }],
    templateUrl: './js/templates/hostelgridbed.html'
  }
})
```

```
.directive('hostelGridDay', function(StaysFactory){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      config: '=',
      date: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,element){
    },
    controller: ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope,$rootScope){
      $scope.switchStay = function(evt, data){
        console.log(data);
        // Here. How can I access this controller's $scope
      }
      $scope.$on('SwitchStay', $scope.switchStay);
    }],
    templateUrl: './js/templates/hostelgridday.html'
  }
})
```

I get data from $broadcast ok, it's all good. Except that I need to access the directive's $scope from within $scope.switchStay function.
Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: The code I quoted is inside directive's $scope. I need to access the same $scope that has switchStay, from within it.

Comment: I just answered thinking you were not speaking about the same `$scope`. What is your question so? Inside the function you can simply use `$scope` and you will access it...

Comment: No, you won't. There's no scope inside the function.

Comment: what do you mean with: "there is no scope inside the function"?

Comment: @Pablo: you are mistaken; in the code you give you can indeed simply reference the same `$scope` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you `$broadcast` or `$emit` the event from the directive, you could send also the directive's scope as parameter. It should work, but this is actually awful and a really bad practice.

What you have to do in these cases is to add a callback parameter to the directive (`&`) and provide the `switchStay` function as callback, and simply trigger it from the directive, passing the parameters that you need to access inside the function.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: The problem is that the directive that $broadcast isn't the same as the one that $scope.$on. How would it be better in this case?

Comment: That's exactly the case when to use the `&` parameters as callback

Comment: Just updated the code. I can't understand what you mean